# Why is my render mode all pixellated when using quick render?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to follow the most beginner tutorials: put some colored cubes and a lamp and a 'quick smoke' monkey head in space and push alt-a to render them.

But it looks broken with the Cycles renderer:
[image]

and with the Blender renderer nothing happens at all:
[image]

I've tried switching CUDA on and off in the user settings in case it was my graphics card but that makes no difference.

Any ideas what's wrong please?

Comment: you simply can't render smoke animation in real time with ray tracing unless you have a really REALLY powerfull computer

Comment: In fact You have to BAKE it during first cycle and then You could see it perfectly fast but in SOLID MODE (smoke could be seen in ViewPort). As Diogo wrote, if You want to see it rendered, get a computer with 4 x 1080ti ;).